# Open file dialog does not open file from network drive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I have the problem that I'm not able to load a file from a network share (details next paragraph), because I got the error message: "File xxxx cannot be read" in my WinForms application. I do not got any result back from dialog, because it does not let me continue.
Can you help?

[Screenshot error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86nKh.jpg)

The network drive is connected with an user credential, that is not the Windows user ("Connect using different credentials").

I tried with the option CheckFileExists on true and also on false. But no difference in the result.

I also try to use the *openFileDialogExcel.FileOk* Event, but the error message pops up before the event will be fired.

Here is the code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialogExcel;
openFileDialogExcel.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx";
openFileDialogExcel.CheckFileExists = false;
DialogResult result = openFileDialogExcel.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK && importer != null) {
...
}
```

By the way, is there a possibility to check if the application has read/write rights on such a share? Because my way to get the access rules and to check the current identities the user has, was not successful:

```
var rules = File.GetAccessControl(fileName).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));

// Get the identity of the current user and the groups that the user is in.
var groups = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups;
string sidCurrentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;

// Check if reading to the file is explicitly denied for this user or a group the user is in.
if (rules.OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>().Any(r => (groups.Contains(r.IdentityReference) || r.IdentityReference.Value == sidCurrentUser) && r.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny && (r.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadData) == FileSystemRights.ReadData))
                    return false;

// Check if reading is allowed
return rules.OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>().Any(r => (groups.Contains(r.IdentityReference) || r.IdentityReference.Value == sidCurrentUser) && r.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow && (r.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadData) == FileSystemRights.ReadData);
```

could not be successful, because the current user has even no access this resource, but the user with the credentials, given for the network share. Currently I solved the problem, by File.OpenRead or File.OpenWrite and catch the exceptions, which is not ideal.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: [WNetUseConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetuseconnectionw) -- [WNetCancelConnection2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetcancelconnection2w)

Comment: I do not have the password of the user. I do not want to ma a networkdrive or remove a networkdrive programatically. I need to know if the current user has write access to the network drive/forlder.

Comment: If the current logged on User is not the same credential used to access the remote resource, you either allow the User to specify the actual credentials, or you try to access the resource and catch the exception, as you're doing. I don't see what else you could do, if you cannot know / use the correct credentials. -- It's common practice, when accessing the File System, to catch the exception when a File/Directory cannot be accessed, for different reasons. I.e., you have no use in creating a `WindowsPrincipal` with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` when this Identity is never used.

Comment: My problem is that the default control (OpenFileDialog) from C# does not let the user close the window, if the selection is on a network drive, which is connected the described way. So the user need to select an inappropriate file to be able to close the window.

Comment: Check the Dialog's validation properties. Perform the validation yourself instead of relying on the default behavior.